# On ec2 how do I use navigation shortcut keys?

Tags: bash, terminal, amazon-ec2

Whenever I ssh to ec2 I notice that ctr+a (beginning of line), ctrl+e, and other navigation keys do not work in terminal.

Is there a way to set up my ec2 terminal so that I can use these navigation shortcut keys?

Comment: It depends on the editor you're using. Look up the keyboard shortcuts for it, whether it's nano, vi, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc, include `set -o emacs` to activate those keybindings.